# Creating some type of buffer for CUPS print jobs

Tags: c, cups

TL;DR: Need to optimize CUPS jobs. The old and optimized version I've been using prints 30 labels in 10 seconds, the newer unoptimized prints 1 in 16 seconds.

I don't really have any experience besides setting up CUPS and less yet with CUPS API, but now I have to create some sort of buffer that takes any number of files and then send to the printer instead of creating print jobs for each file.
I've searched a lot, the whole day and yet didn't find anything that could solve this problem.

It's possible to use cupsCreateDestJob from the CUPS API to do that? Or I can use some shell command? Merge the files?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you are needing to do, CUPS uses the default print queue to hold jobs already. Why would you want/need to duplicate that.? (you can view the status with `lpq`) Understanding what you need to do other than just allocating an copying print jobs to a block of memory would help.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks. Edited the question to reflect the exact problem.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Would it work to use the job from one file (copy it) and just change what changed on the label in that job and resubmit the updated job? That way if you have 100 jobs, with 100 different text to display, you create one job, duplicate it 100 times and update the text on the other 99 directly? Essentially you would just be changing where the text-merge was occurring. From per-print to post-print?

Comment: Depending on your printer type, the [HP Printer Job Language Tech Reference](https://developers.hp.com/system/files/PJL_Technical_Reference_Manual.pdf) may help.

Comment: Theoretically it's easy, your solution would work fine. But how to implement on the other hand is the hard part. The files and control that go to the cups spool are binaries compiled from IPP files, so isn't that easy to see and modify their content. Unless the files are preprocessed in other directory that i have never heard of.

Comment: This is not a "C" question, and it should be migrated to "Linux & UNIX" probably.

Comment: @U.Windl can be C related. The API is written in C and the solution may be found there.

Comment: @KamuriYou should provide much more details then.

Comment: @U.Windl and what you suggest? How can this question be improved?

Comment: @Kamuri Read my first comment. If you think it's C programming issue, present some C code; otherwise it's probably an administration or configuration problem.

Comment: @U.Windl so shoud i copy and paste all the code from cups api? i'm here seeking for help, to ask if someone has a MINIMAL idea of how this thing can get done. It's a configuration problem? show some solution,that'll prove your point. While no solution is presented to this question, it'll still having chances of being categorized on C.

Comment: @Kamuri Maybe first explain your problem in a detail that anyone can see it's a C problem. Probably it'll be easier to sole your problem if you file a bug report directly at CUPS.